# Ruby-on-rails vs ruby-on-rails3

Tags: discussion, tags

Since ruby on rails v3 was released recently, some new tags appeared: [rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails3) and [ruby-on-rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails3).

The question is: should we merge `rails3` into `ruby-on-rails3` or merge both of them into `ruby-on-rails`.

While it is true that rails 3 has some specificity, I don't think that'd be a good idea to keep track of framework version in tags, but that's just me. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

Merging it to `ruby_on_rails3` would make most sense.

There might still be people around using `v1` or `v2` of `rails` and would like to ask questions based upon these.

E.g. : C# also has multiple tags targeting its version. [ `c#`, `c#2.0`, `c#3.0`, `c#4.0` ]

Comment: don't you think it will lead to a lot of posts tagged ruby-on-rails and ruby-on-rails3 ?