# Does the ruby-on-rails tag apply to all questions that also have ruby-on-rails-# tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-hierarchy

Is it intended for people to tag all questions where `ruby-on-rails-3` is appropriate with the `ruby-on-rails` tag as well?

This question has been proposed in a comment on [a previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/ruby-on-rails-vs-ruby-on-rails3) but was never directly addressed. I have a compulsion to clean up tags on questions I answer and I go back and forth on whether `ruby-on-rails` even needs to exist as a tag.

I understand the notion that people will have questions that apply to specific versions of rails, and I agree with that notion as well. It seems to me, however, that `ruby-on-rails` becomes redundant at this point. If the person asking the question always tags the question with whatever version of rails they are using, any additional rails tag is redundant. You could argue that the question might apply to multiple versions of rails, but in this seemingly uncommon case, you could easily just tag the question with `ruby-on-rails-2` and `ruby-on-rails-3`. As such, using `ruby-on-rails` to tag version-agnostic questions seems like a poor choice.

Because of this, the only reason I can see for keeping around the `ruby-on-rails` tag is to make it easy to follow all rails questions. If this is the reason for keeping it and this reason is accepted behavior under Stack Overflow, then it stands to reason that the data organizer inside me should be making sure all rails questions also have the `ruby-on-rails` tag. I want to be sure of this before I go all buck-wild on question tags, however.

If this *isn't* the reason for keeping a base tag for a language, I'd be very interested in knowing the actual reasoning.

It's worth noting that, were a tag hierarchy in place, it'd pretty much do the job of tagging all `ruby-on-rails-#` questions as `ruby-on-rails` all by itself. A quick search on meta shows that this idea has been proposed before, however, so I won't harp on it.