# Why do we have a Ruby-on-Rails-3 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Ruby on Rails 3 may be different from Ruby on Rails 2, but Ruby on Rails 3 has been around for **2 years** now (see [Ruby-on-rails vs ruby-on-rails3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/ruby-on-rails-vs-ruby-on-rails3)), so I think every question tagged with `ruby-on-rails` is about version 3 now. So why do we still have both a tag `ruby-on-rails` (63183 questions) and a tag `ruby-on-rails-3` (21137 questions)?

If the question is specific about the current version, I expect it only have the `ruby-on-rails` tag. Another tag for the version is only helpful if it's not about the *current version*, e.g. `ruby-on-rails-2` (145 questions).

So why do we still need the tag `ruby-on-rails-3` with **21137** questions? can't we make it a synonym to `ruby-on-rails` now?

In my perspective, a version in it's **own tag** isn't very informative, it's enough to have the version noted in the question. People that follow `ruby-on-rails` will know when the problem is version specific and people working with other versions will understand most of the content anyway.

Comment: We have `.NET-2.0`, `.NET-3.5` and `.NET-4.0` tags, because the feature set is substantially different among these versions, and answers to questions can change significantly based on the version being used. You need to convince us that these differences are insignificant with respect to Ruby on Rails versions, and I don't think you've adequately made that case in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, but a *version-specific* tag used **21137** times for the *current* version isn't that specifc anymore and has lost what it was meant to communicate. See also [You should strongly avoid creating version tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/142791)

Comment: That's an argument for people not using the tag wrongly, not for the tag not existing in the first place.

Comment: The idea that a base framework name always relates to the "current" version is silly. That means that old questions will be suddenly tagged incorrectly when a new version comes out and fixes or changes things the question was related to. If anything, base framework names _should always_ have a version indicator for no other reason than _to prevent tag rot_.

Comment: I still see questions related to Rails 2.x once in a while. There is a ruby-in-rail-3.2 tag as well, i think. Though I'm not sure, if the version tags really help much, since most questions are tagged ruby-on-rails independent of the questions content. There are a lot of questions with old answers which would need updates. I have discussed this a few weeks ago [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115320/what-to-do-about-deprecated-questions-answers)

Comment: @thorstenmuller: Yes, that was also my point, version-tags doesn't add much value. *Ruby-on-Rails is Ruby-on-Rails* as [Jeff wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags/85744#85744).